# Wordpress Hostname doubles in my image url link

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress site, when I try to upload the wordpress the some of my images tends to be not found. I did inspect the images the right link should be like these:

http://www.thelushcompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Website-graphics-Fruitas-Logo-476x477pix.jpg

But wordpress generates it to be like these:

http://www.thelushcompany.com/www.thelushcompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Website-graphics-Fruitas-Logo-476x477pix.jpg

How can I fix it ? I am running out of options.

Comment: Please, provide your code.

Comment: how did you printed those images in front-end ? please provide that code, uploading seems correct.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Bon Geomar Barriatos,

If you have transferred your local/sandbox WordPress installation to a live server, try to check your database file for the live site URL, there you may have added website URL twice while replacing the local/sandbox URL. 
You just need to change the website URL in your database, so that it will connect with your live WordPress site.

For example: replace http://www.thelushcompany.com/www.thelushcompany.com with http://www.thelushcompany.com in the database.

Comment: You mean the siteurl under the wp_option in the database, right ? I already change it. But nothing happens.
http://imgur.com/wVY3uQH.jpg

Comment: That is also one way to do it, else you may download your database file and check/find your website URL in it using any Text Editor(eg: Notepad++).
If you find any repeated link of your URL one after another, kindly replace it.